# UEFI BIOS: APM power-on option set, but computer does not power on when power comes back

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, bios, uefi

**ENVIRONMENT**

```
Asus VivoMini UN62-M033R
Intel Core i3-4030U @ 1.90 GHz 1.90 GHz
UEFI BIOS 0226 x64 Build 11/05/2014 9.5.20.1742
Windows 8.1 64-bit
```

**WINDOWS SETTINGS**

Windows Power Options: power button shuts down computer.

**BIOS SETTINGS**

BIOS -> Advanced -> APM:

```
ErP Ready: Disabled
Restore AC Power Loss: Power on
Power on by PCIE: Disabled
Power on by RTC: Disabled
```

**BEHAVIOR**

Pressing the computer's Power button: computer shuts down.

I assume it still draws some current, to react on wake-on-LAN events; so the UEFI BIOS should still monitor the power.

Now I disconnect the power physically.

When I plug the power cord back in, I'd expect the computer to power on, right? (It does on 2 other computers, having i7 CPUs.)

But nope, the thing doesn't start up; I have to press the Power button.

What did I not consider?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to auto-boot after power-loss. It is correctly 'restoring state'... which was 'shut down'.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware/firmware bug to me.  Have you tried flashing the firmware?

Comment: +1 for updating the BIOS. Your setting of "Restore AC Power Loss" is OK, the system should turn on when AC power comes back.

Comment: @Tetsujin, this is not correct. In BIOS -> Advanced -> APM -> Restore AC Power Loss there is an Option "Last state" which, when selected, would do what you say. However, my setting is "Power On".

Comment: fair enough - mine does exactly that, but only has 2 options, on or off. On == last state. btw, please don't put your fix in the question, make it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, the issue was a BIOS bug, and updating the BIOS fixed it.  The computer was reflashed with UEFI BIOS 1307 x64 Build 10/18/2016 10.0.45.1024 to fix the problem.

(I'm delighted that worked for you!)